# Inline assembly confusion when using parameters

Tags: assembly, rust

I'm experimenting with Rust's inline assembly feature on x86_64 Linux. I've written a simple program that calls the `exit` syscall with the value 23.

```
#![feature(asm)]

fn main() {
  unsafe {
    asm!(
      "
      mov $$60, %rax
      mov $$23, %rdi
      syscall
      "
      :
      :
      : "%rax", "%rdi"
    );
  }
}
```

This program works fine, I can `rustc exit.rs; ./exit; echo $?` and get 23. Now I want to make the asm code interface with rust. So I pass the 23 in from rust rather than hardcoding it in the assembly.

```
#![feature(asm)]

fn main() {
  unsafe {
    asm!(
      "
      mov $$60, %rax
      mov $0, %rdi
      syscall
      "
      :
      : "r"(23)
      : "%rax", "%rdi"
    );
  }
}
```

Once again, this works. Now I try to pass 23 in using a variable.

```
#![feature(asm)]

fn main() {
  let x = 23i;
  unsafe {
    asm!(
      "
      mov $$60, %rax
      mov $0, %rdi
      syscall
      "
      :
      : "r"(x)
      : "%rax", "%rdi"
    );
  }
}
```

And this breaks. It exits with 60 rather than 23. Looking at the generated assembly shows why:

```
movq    $23, (%rsp)
movq    (%rsp), %rax
#APP

movq    $60, %rax
movq    %rax, %rdi
syscall
```

The compiler tries to save 23 into `%rax` but then `%rax` gets overwritten by 60 in the inline assembly.

So, is this a compiler bug? Or do I just not now how to use inline assembly? (The latter is quite possible).

**Edit:** As per request, the LLVM IR output is:

```
; ModuleID = 'exit.0.rs'
target datalayout = "e-i64:64-f80:128-n8:16:32:64-S128"
target triple = "x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu"

; Function Attrs: uwtable
define internal void @_ZN4main20h2dd3717eeddb6da6eaaE() unnamed_addr #0 {
entry-block:
  %x = alloca i64
  store i64 23, i64* %x
  %0 = load i64* %x
  call void asm "\0A      mov $$60, %rax\0A      mov $0, %rdi\0A      syscall\0A      ", "r,~{%rax},~{%rdi},~{dirflag},~{fpsr},~{flags}"(i64 %0), !srcloc !0
  ret void
}

define i64 @main(i64, i8**) unnamed_addr #1 {
top:
  %2 = call i64 @_ZN2rt10lang_start20h6ebacfb5a732c9b9PfyE(i8* bitcast (void ()* @_ZN4main20h2dd3717eeddb6da6eaaE to i8*), i64 %0, i8** %1)
  ret i64 %2
}

declare i64 @_ZN2rt10lang_start20h6ebacfb5a732c9b9PfyE(i8*, i64, i8**) unnamed_addr #1

attributes #0 = { uwtable "split-stack" }
attributes #1 = { "split-stack" }

!0 = metadata !{i32 21}
```

Comment: Could you please post the disassembled LLVM IR? That should be helpful in diagnosing the problem.

Comment: I don't speak 'rust'.  However, in gcc (which uses a similar format for asm), specifying rax and rdi as clobbers should prevent them from being selected as the register to use for the parameter.  In fact, gcc's docs specifically say `Clobber descriptions may not in any way overlap with an input or output operand.`  Since rust is not gcc, I couldn't say if this is a bug, but for gcc I'd try using constraints like `"a"(60), "D"(x)` and change your string to be just `syscall`.  FWIW.

Answer (score 3):

Solved, thanks to @pczarn on github. The issue was that the list of clobbers should be written `"rax", "rdi"` not `"%rax", "%rdi"`.